# Edge weights on trees

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm,
                level 1/.style={sibling distance=1.3cm},
                level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm}]
                level 3/.style={sibling distance=0.8cm}]
                \tikzstyle{every node}=[circle,draw]

                \node (Root) [red] {e}

                child {
                    node {a}
                    child { 
                        node {b} 
                        child {node {c}} 
                    }
                    child { node {d} }
                }
                child {
                    node {h}
                }
                child {
                    node {f} 
                    child { node {g} }
                };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I produce this image:

[image]

My question is how I can produce edge weights on this image for example if I wanted an edge weight from e to a or a to b, how would I produce it for this tree?

Im using this library:     \usetikzlibrary{trees}

Comment: what you mean with "edge weight"?

Comment: @Zarko Edge weight meaning if there is a edge from a to b in my tree above , there can be a 5 written above it (edge weight of 5) if that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You can use `edge from parent`, but this may require switching back.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm,
                level 1/.style={sibling distance=1.3cm},
                level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm}]
                level 3/.style={sibling distance=0.8cm}]
                \tikzstyle{every node}=[circle,draw]

                \node (Root) [red] {e}

                child {
                    node {a}
                    child { 
                        node {b} 
                        edge from parent[blue]
                        child {node[black] {c}
                        edge from parent[black]} 
                    }
                    child { node {d} }
                 edge from parent[double]
                }
                child {
                    node {h}
                }
                child {
                    node {f} 
                    child { node {g} }
                };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

like this?

[image]

for labels of edges serve `edge from parent node[<options>] {<label>}`. it should be on correct place (after node before it you like to have label), see mwe below:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
   level distance = 1.5cm,
   level 1/.style = {sibling distance=1.3cm},
   level 2/.style = {sibling distance=1.0cm},
   level 3/.style = {sibling distance=0.8cm},
every node/.style = {circle,draw},
       lbl/.style = {rectangle, draw=none, #1,% position
                     font=\footnotesize}
                        ]
%
\node (Root) [red] {e}
    child {node {a}
        child {node {b}
            child {node {c}
            edge from parent node[lbl=left] {$bc$}
            }
        edge from parent node[lbl=left] {$ab$}
       }
    child {node {d}
    edge from parent node[lbl=right] {$ad$}
        }
    edge from parent node[lbl=left] {$ea$}
      }
    child { node {h}}
    child { node {f}
        child { node {g} }
          };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

used labels of edges are selected so that indicate nodes name, where edge begin and end. explanation about this you can find in *21.6 Edges From the Parent Node*, page 323 in "tikz & pgf manual", version 3.0.1a,